# Add css classes to <body> in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-1

How to add css class to the body tag on specific route? I tried to use `body` tag in a handlebars template but didn't work...

**Update:**
After some googling I came with this solution. Not sure that this is the best way to do this, but it works.

```
App.SomeRoute = Em.Route.extend
  activate: ->
    Em.$('body').addClass 'some-class'

  deactivate: ->
    Em.$('body').removeClass 'some-class'
```

Comment: You mean your HTML body? I'm unsure what you're asking. Please post some code to help!

Comment: you can as well `removeClass` in `deactivate` hook or so

Comment: @sabithpocker oh! I didn't think about it. I thought on the other route the class will be removed automatically. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for posting, I was just able to solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614032/emberjs-add-class-or-id-to-the-body-tag/23616083?noredirect=1#comment36269024_23616083